# Access Object inside Array in React JSON API Call

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object, iteration

I'm making an API call that returns JSON data in a React app. The data contains an object nested inside an array. I want to access the data within the object.

I am able to access and iterate through the array data and log it with this:

```
loadSearchResults = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
var search = this.state.value;

axios.get(`https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=` + `search`)
  .then(res => {
    const results = res.data.collection.items;
    console.log(results);
  });
```

}

This logs out the array. [image]

I want to access the data inside each object. [image]

How do I iterate and display the object data (i.e. description, center, media type)? In other words, after iterating through the array how do I iterate through the objects inside the array?

Answer (score 0):

Object.values() should work:

```
  axios
  .get(`https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=` + `search`)
  .then(res => res.data.collection.items)
  .then(json => {
    json.map(obj => console.log(Object.values(obj)))
  })
```

to render data inside of a `<div>` (assuming this component has state/ is a class):

```
axios
  .get(`https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=` + `search`)
  .then(res => res.data.collection.items)
  .then(json => {
    json.map(obj => this.setState({ allTheValues: Object.values(obj) }))
  })

render() {return (<div>{this.state.allTheValues.map(value => value)}</div>)}
```

The tricky part is that youre inside of a promise, which is asynchronous, but that's a whole other issue

Comment: Tried it and getting an error: res.json is not a function

Comment: ok, `replace res.json()` with the original `res.data.collection.items`
Because the Object.values() was the root problem i believe

Comment: That works and successfully console.logs the data but I'm trying to render the data and display it in divs.

Comment: I can normally do this when the JSON data is an array inside an array or an object inside an object, but something about it being an object inside an array is throwing me off. Caught between using .map if it's an array and using Object.keys if it's an object.

Comment: Objects inside of array shouldnt throw you off. If the component youre working in has state- try to use the revision i made in my original answer. The tricky part is that youre inside of  a promise, which is asynchronous, but that's a whole other issue